# AC Analysis Mindset

Tags: ac, filter, analysis, theory

I'm just trying to solidify my foundational knowledge of ac analysis. So when approached with a basic circuit, lets say a RLC circuit, should my first instinct be to convert each group of components into a Z category. For example, when looking at active op-amp filters (miller integrator with inverting source and resistor)should my mindset be to group the feedback loop as a Z2, and  the inverting resistor as Z1 and carry out my gain analysis of Av = Vo/Vi = -Z2/Z1? Or rather what is the most effective way to think about ac analysis. I want to learn how other people think about analysis, this helps me the most in becoming creative.

Comment: I think it really depends on the circuit, and how you are trying to analyze it.

Comment: My first instinct is to recognize the topology of the circuit and think about what AC characteristic it will have but, others may think differently and this basically means you are asking for opinions. Opinion based questions are not generally the best format for EE and may be closed.

Comment: In theory, this is not an opinion-based question. This is an open forum of thinking pertaining to a certain topic. All theories lead to the same answer. I'm asking for methods of reaching the answer. So, to clarify further, an opinion leaves room of suspicion or doubt. I'm looking for certainty.

Comment: "open forum of thinking pertaining to a certain topic" - this reads as soliciting opinions to me. EE is not a forum, it is a question and answer site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think - in general - your approach is OK (converting into Z category). However, you must be aware of the limits using this method:

- Linear circuits (or linearized around a suitable DC operating point),
- Small-signal operation, and
- Sinusoidal waveforms.

Comment: Might as well explicitly say "Steady state"  (though pure sinusoidal implies it).